# Retrieve the key value in the Dictionary

Tags: python

I have two loops, one to retrieve the key (Email address) and store it into a variable and another loop to retrieve the value of the keys (List containing data). However, after the script runs, the final key is repeated.

I have attempted shifting the `for` loops around and attempted creating a new block of code that puts the keys into a list and just retrieve them one by one, but it didn't work.

#### Code

[image: Code Image]

```
import re 
import os

userInfoDict = dict() 
newDict = eval(open("/home/ad.ilstu.edu/keschm1/IT170/UserLog//myData.txt").read())
list = []
#print(newDict)
email = ' '
firstName = ' ' 
lastName = ' ' 
IP = ' '

for keys in newDict.keys():
   email = keys

for values in newDict.values():
   firstName = values[0]
   lastName = values[1]
   IP = values[2]
   #print('The name is: ' + firstName + ' ' +lastName +' the IP is: '  + IP +'\n')
   list.append(email + ": " + firstName + " " + lastName +":" + IP)

file = open("userInfo.txt", "w")
for items in list:
   file.write(items + '\n')
   #print(items)
file.close()
```

This is the result when printing onto a txt document

> hosack@comcast.com.:Glen Wilson:172.39.112.76
>   hosack@comcast.com.:Cindy Tady:123.18.19.20 hosack@comcast.com.:Emma
>   Lim:11.11.11.11 hosack@comcast.com.:Anna Smith:172.28.19.15
>   hosack@comcast.com.:Jack Hosack:196.88.45.23

Comment: Please include code, not images of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for keys in newDict.keys():
    email = keys
```

What do you think this does?  This assigns each key in newDict to the same **email** variable, one after another.  So **email** will end up set to the last **keys** value you processed from the **newDict** dictionary.  Probably not what you want.

Since this is the only way you set **email**, it will always be set to the same value when used later on in your code.

What you probably want is something like this:

```
for email, values in newDict.items():
   firstName = values[0]
   lastName = values[1]
   IP = values[2]
   #print('The name is: ' + firstName + ' ' +lastName +' the IP is: '  + IP +'\n')
   list.append(email + ": " + firstName + " " + lastName +":" + IP)
```